# Cannot convert value of type 'UIView' to expected argument type 'UIWebView'

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, uiview, uiwebview

I am using cordova-plugin-iosrtc.

I am experiencing the following error.

> iOSRTCApp-master/platforms/ios/iOSRTCApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/iosrtcPlugin.swift:622:24:
>   Cannot convert value of type 'UIView' to expected argument type
>   'UIWebView'

According to repository,I should not get this error.

Here is the code snippet

```
let pluginMediaStreamRenderer = PluginMediaStreamRenderer(
            webView:self.webView!,
            eventListener: { (data: NSDictionary) -> Void in
                let result = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsDictionary: data as [NSObject : AnyObject])

                // Allow more callbacks.
                result.setKeepCallbackAsBool(true);
                self.emit(command.callbackId, result: result)
            }
        )
```

I tried to cast UIView to UIwebview but that's also not happening.

Comment: You are using Cordova iOS >= 4, which is not supported. Downgrade to 3.9.2.

Comment: https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues/142

Comment: It has been supported since version 3.0.0: https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc#version-300

Comment: @saghul - When 5.2.0 corodva installed no compilation error but it showing Apache Cordova "Device is ready".But not showing apprtc.appspot.com any ideas

Comment: That's a different issue. iOSAppRTC is unsupported so you'll need to adapt it.

Comment: No actually that application is designed for supporting apprtc only ...Please have a look at here https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc#demo-application

Answer (score 5):

This is some version incompatibility problem.

Try to install the following cordova version and add the iOS plugin both are compatible

```
npm install -g cordova@5.2.0
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: no compilation error now but it showing Apache Cordova "Device is ready".But not showing apprtc.appspot.com any ideas