# Cordova iOS RTC plugin is not working

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I have added the iOS RTC plugin then if I open the project in xcode and run it in device its not showing apprtc.appspot.com.

It shows

> Apache Cordova "Device is ready"

Here is the github repo [link](https://github.com/eface2face/iOSRTCApp)

This question is somewhat related with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39677167/5730180)

I am confused someone kindly guide me !